# What is the most efficient and correct way of handling PHP array variables within JavaScript and being able it obtain those values using indexing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

**THE QUESTION**

What is the most efficient and correct way of handling PHP array variables within JavaScript and being able it obtain those values using indexing.

I have a MYSQL database and have a PHP script that creates an indexed row array of the database information.

Now that this information is within the array i am comfortable about echoing this data on screen from within PHP.

i.e.

```
echo $lastplayed[1]['artist'];
```

My next step is to take the array into JavaScript so that i can use the variable information to display data on screen, make calculations and create an Ajax timer that looks for a value from a variable and refreshes the page..

Its basically a internet radio station that will display what is and has been played and when a counter reaches zero will refresh the page. (the counter being time left of a song)

I could echo each variable into a separate PHP script and then use JavaScript to call each of those PHP scripts that contain the different variables **(This seems long-winded) AND puts unnecessary request strain on the MYSQL server**

****I really feel that there must be a better way of transferring and handling the data, surely there must be some type of bridge between PHP and JavaScript, should i be looking into JSON ?**

So my end result is to be able to take an indexed array from PHP, transfer this array into JavaScript and be able to call on different variables from within the array using indexing (i.e call the variable that resides in result 3 column 3)

And while this is happening i will be using separate PHP and JavaScript files...

**Here is my code for the PHP part.**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

require_once("DbConnect.php");

$sql = "SELECT `artist`, `title`, `label`, `albumyear`, `date_played`, `duration`,
`picture` FROM historylist  ORDER BY `date_played` DESC LIMIT 5 ";

$result = $db->query($sql);

$lastplayed = array();

$i = 1;

while ($row=$result->fetch_object()) {
$lastplayed[$i]['artist']      = $row->artist;
$lastplayed[$i]['title']       = $row->title;
$lastplayed[$i]['label']       = $row->label;
$lastplayed[$i]['albumyear']   = $row->albumyear;
$lastplayed[$i]['date_played'] = $row->date_played;
$lastplayed[$i]['duration']    = $row->duration;
$lastplayed[$i]['picture']     = $row->picture;

$i++;


}

$starttime = strtotime($lastplayed[1]['date_played']);
$curtime = time();
$timeleft = $starttime+round($lastplayed[1]['duration']/1000)-$curtime;
$secsremain = (round($lastplayed[1]['duration'] / 1000)-($curtime-$starttime))

?>
```

***Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated and thanks so much for your time.***

Justin.

**PROGRESS:**

**Thanks for the comments, i really need to take a JavaScript course at this point...**

Now i have created a new **output.PHP** file that does the following

```
<?php
require_once("dblastplayedarray.php");
echo json_encode($lastplayed);
?>
```

So this file now echo's out the data i need in a JSON format from my array $lastplayed.

@VCNinc you say that i now can use the following code to take the data into JavaScript

```
<script>
var array = <?=json_encode($lastplayed)?>;
</script>
```

Please could you detail where i put the path information in this code so that the program knows where to look for the .PHP file output.php

Am i doing this right.. should i be printing the data into another .PHP file and then use your code to take the array into JavaScript..

Thanks

Justin.

Comment: `should i be looking into JSON?` Yes, you should be. For encoding your array, there's [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode)

Answer (score 0):

JSON is the bridge!

You can "export" the variable to a json string and print on the output:

```
echo json_encode($lastplayed);
```

TIP: if the php file is used to show a html GUI AND you still want output a JSON too, you can create a GET variable like "&json=1" and, before output your HTML GUI, you do a IF. This way tou can use the same php file to output a GUI and the JSON. WHen you do the request via ajax, you call using the "&json=1".

```
if(isset($_GET['json']) && $_GET['json']==1){
   echo json_encode($lastplayed);
   exit;
}
```

Then, use AJAX to download this JSON string by calling your php script.

```
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    //here the 'json' variable will be the array
    //so you can interact on it if you want
    $.each( json, function( key, value ) {
       alert( key + ": " + value ); //here you can do anything you want
    });
});
```

Comment: this works but is overly complicated when you can simply output JSON into a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PHP array `$array`, you can easily export it into JavaScript like this:

```
<script>
var array = <?=json_encode($array)?>;
</script>
```

(and from that point you can manipulate it as JSON...)